# Pull field values of Drupal Views Custom Field $data variable?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-field-api

In Drupal 6, I'm using the [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) module to insert some php into my View. The helper text in the php CustomField reads:

> $data: contains the retrieved record from the database (e.g. $data->nid).

Okay... seems pretty straightforward. So, I have a custom field named `field_short_title` that's being output in the view. Now how do I pull that value out of the `$data` variable? I've tried the following, but no luck:

`$data->field_short_title`

`$data->field_short_title_value`

`$data->node_data_field_short_title.field_short_title_value`

Surely this is just some kind of Drupal syntax error on my part... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh... I used `<?php print_r ($data) ?>` to see what's going on with that $data variable. Here's what I was looking for:

```
node_data_field_short_title_field_short_title_value
```

So the whole thing looks like this:

```
<?php echo $data->node_data_field_short_title_field_short_title_value ?>
```

Intuitive, isn't it? Sigh...

Answer (score 1):

Use `print_r($data)` It will shows all view field machine name, You can use that name in your PHP code Now you can get view field values where ever you want..